# Wine will run it no longer

Tags: wine

I was wondering if anyone knew how to get this particular app working. it's not a normal app and it requires wine to use but I was able to get a copy from my teacher. Sadly it requires libraries from windows xp and OS 9, if I can get it working again then the administration might integrate Ubuntu into our school and not have such "virus friendly" OS's...

[image: virus friendly os]

Now, a few might think it doesn't work at all but the first time I used it I did manage to get it to work

[image: error2]

I was using 1.6.2 Wine I believe, but, I had to reinstall Ubuntu because I broke it... again. # installations later and I am now here, unable to get it to work again. I used 1.6.2, 1.8.5, and the experimental 1.9.23 but it just won't start up. There are 6 applications just like that one and they work but this one, SigDig and 2 others stopped working. Is there a specific library I need or did the packages change? I just need to get them running again. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try starting it in a terminal with the command `wine SigDig2009.exe`. Then add any error messages generated to your question.  It seems like a pretty old and obscure windows application!

Comment: Have you tried running the application in compatibility mode? Run `winecfg` from terminal, add the .exe and set it to *Windows XP compatibility*. If this is for school you could write your own application as well :)

Comment: I did try the compatibility mode and it didn't help much, sadly. The program is old but the computer it would run on is older, 14 years old. I grabbed EVERY dll from windows xp and shoved it into a lubuntu device and it works, graphics fixed and all, the only issue is I have to search through 2 GB of dll's to find the ones that work (to avoid security issues on a school network). So wine no longer downloads 1 or 2 specific dll's. Is there a linux app to track what dll's a wine program is calling for? like, a terminal output of calls. I wish I knew how to program so much at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after going through the code in all the files I managed to find what dll's it was looking for and grabbed what I could from a legitimate version of Windows XP. Apparently the wine version I first used was a slightly customized fork. Now, running the standard repository version and the new dll package the programs work. And no, the built-in variations wine offered didn't work, so the real deal was needed. Now the school is (un)happily running Ubuntu (it breached into their network...) but they plan to use Linux in the future now so, hooray for Linux.

I do apologize if what I asked was not even close to sufficient for the response requirements.

Edit: if anyone someone magically gets a copy of these (as far as I know the last copies are with "us") then I can either tell the dll's or give a drive link to the ones used.